# Loading dataset in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to load a new dataset in R which is in the same working directory( "C:\R" )
e.g "Aust.rda"
but it is not working

> x <- "Aust.rda"
>   data( x )
>   Warning message:
>   In data(x) : data set ‘x’ not found

I've also tried

> data( "Aust.rda" )
>   Warning message:
>   In data("Aust.rda") : data set ‘Aust.rda’ not found

Comment: Try `readRDS('Aust.rda')` or `load('Aust.rda')`

Comment: How can i display Aust's data on R ??

Comment: Just assign to a object `a1 <- readRDS('Aust.rda')` and see what `a1` has by just typing `a1` in the console or `str(a1)`

Comment: Error in readRDS("Aust.rda") : unknown input format ... error generated when I'm doing it

Comment: Have you tried the second option?

Comment: Yes, I've tried both

Comment: No, it's no giving any error.. but I can't display Aust's data  > x <- load('Aust.rda')
> x
[1] "val"

Comment: now try typing `val`.  `load()` returns the *names* of the loaded objects.

Comment: > val.load()
Error: could not find function "val.load"

Comment: And don't assign `load()` to an object, as Nikos wrote just type `load("Aust.rda")`, check via `ls()` your workspace and access the object that you find there. Assuming your previous comment that object is called `val`...

Comment: @DanielFischer .. I did exactly same but when I'm using ls() ..I can't find Aust dataset there

Comment: If you load the file Aust.rda, it doesn't necessary mean that it also contains an object called Aust, it is just a filename, anything could be there inside. What happens if you start a new R session, type `load("Aust.rda")`and then type `ls()`? I am almost sure you will see something there, and as I wrote, it seems that the obect inside is called `val`, so after loading it, you probably can access it via `val`

Comment: Thanx @DanielFischer ... val is there

Comment: Btw - Ben Bolker wrote that also already. The period is not part of the command, it is just a period in the sentence...

Answer (score 2):

The .rda files are loaded using load(), not readRDS(). Use load() and check your environment. The variables would be there.

Use ls() to see the available variables.

Also, as @roman-luštrik mentions in his comment, please check the file path.